# Docker multistage build

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My dockerfile looks as below :

```
FROM python:2.7 as builder

RUN pip install pika
RUN pip install requests
RUN pip install simplejson
RUN pip install datetime
RUN pip install grequests

RUN pip install urllib
RUN pip install pandas



COPY Action.py ./Action.py
COPY UtilFunctions.py ./UtilFunctions.py

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

FROM apline
WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app /app

CMD [ "python","-u","./Action.py" ]
```

While building -> sudo  docker build --rm -t rule1-test .

Gives following error ->

```
Step 1 : FROM python:2.7 as builder

Error parsing reference: "python:2.7 as builder" is not a valid repository/tag
```

Docker version is as below :

```
Docker version 1.12.6, build 88a4867/1.12.6
```

Is multistage not supported on this version 
I have installed docker on centos machine using

```
 yum install docker
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multi-stage builds are a new feature in Docker 17.05, so you have to update your Docker version to 17.05 or a newer version.

Comment: I have Docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87 and I still see this message: `Error parsing reference: "microsoft/dotnet:2.0-sdk as builder" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format`

Comment: Ah, the boot2docker version is only 17.03. Not sure how it fell out of sync like that.